# If $|r| < 1$, how extreme is $y$ for a change in $x$?

Tags: regression, covariance, standard-error, correlation

This is regarding [one](https://youtu.be/jVntGheqr0Q) of problem sets in Udacity Intro to Statistics course.

**Problem:**
X and Y are given variables, and the correlation coefficient $|r| < 1$, the question is how extreme our prediction of Y compared to change in X.

Choices:
A) Y to be more extreme
B) Y to be as extreme
C) Y to be less extreme
D) Depends on the data.

**[Given solution](https://youtu.be/sMKpvWmev8k):**
My question is in the answer given by them. If $y = bx + a$, then $b = r\dfrac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}$, then

\begin{align}
y = r\dfrac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}x + a  \tag{1}
\end{align}

They take the Z scores of X and Y to arrive at the result.

\begin{align}
z_y = r\dfrac{\sigma_{z_y}}{\sigma_{z_x}}z_x + 0 = rz_x \tag{2}
\end{align}

Equation {2} concludes that since $|r|<1$, $\implies$ $\bigg|\dfrac{z_y}{z_x}\bigg| < 1$, in other words, z score of y will always not vary as much as z score of x variation. Thus, (C) is the answer.

**My question:**
Can't we directly deduce this from equation {1} itself? If so, how? (I mean, you still have unknown variables $\sigma_y, \sigma_x, a$ that could influence the y variation?!) If not, why not?

Comment: What is extreme? any definition?

Comment: sorry by mistake my link was taking to solution video, [here](https://youtu.be/jVntGheqr0Q) is the question video where he defines the problem. It is only here he mentions extreme, so that is it all there is about what he meant by that.

Comment: I still have no idea on extreme after seeing that video.

Comment: From the solution, extreme seems to relate to the likelihood of extreme values, since it's being measured in terms of the z-score. Since $Y$ is a linear function of $X$, the variance of our prediction is $r\sigma_y/\sigma_x$ times the standard deviation of $X$. Using the definition of correlation as $r=\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)/(\sigma_x\sigma_y), you see this factor is less than 1 and that the spread of our prediction is less than the spread of our input.